# Convert an array row of REAL to a comma delimited string

Tags: format, fortran, string-formatting

I have a very old Fortran program which converts data from one text format to another. In one place it handles an array of data allocated as follows:

```
  real*4, allocatable   :: s(:,:) ! is the declaration
  ! ...
  allocate (s(16,k)) ! is the allocation
  ! then, in a loop later on:
  do i=1,k
     write (7,*) (s(j,i),j=1,16)
  end do
```

The output from that code looks like this:

> -1.375000      -1.375000       327277.0       328682.0       2.750000      0.1250000      0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00  0.0000000E+00   1.000000       5.000000       400.0000       1.000000

I need it to look like this:

> -1.375,-1.375,-.125,1.375,1.375,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,1,1

The thing that is most important is that I get a comma to delimit the fields, rather than other whitespace.

Using the `FORMAT` statement, how could that be done?

EDIT: I note that this line: `write (7, "(*(F8.5,:,','))") s(:,i)`

...produces output that looks like this:

```
 3.00000, 4.50000, 1.00000,********, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 5.00000,********, 1.00000
 3.00000, 4.50000,********,********, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000, 5.00000,********, 1.00000
```

I don't know what the `********` signifies; the strings that are supposed to be there are stored as REAL but evaluate to integers like `101` or `52`

Comment: Format statement was deprecated even before your code you think is very old was written. Use format strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use a `FORMAT` statement, it was made effectively obsolescent 25 years ago. Even your "very old" code is not THAT old. Use a format string.

```
write (7,'(9999(f0.3,a))') (s(j,i), ",",j=1,16)
```

if you do not mind Fortran 2008, better is

```
write (7,'(9999(g0))') (s(j,i), ",",j=1,16)
```

Note:

1. It is better not to use unit numbers smaller than 10. They are often pre-connected somewhere.
2. You could even use `'(*(g0))'`, that is also Fortran 2008. `g0` is the universal descriptor for minimal width editing. It can be used for all intrinsic data types.
3. The zero in the width field in the descriptors instructs the compiler to use the minimum width necessary to print the expression.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I think my "very old" program was written by a Fortran77 guy. He was still using `c` comments and column positions on some of his stuff... The unit number is not at issue in this program, which is a short-ish spaghetti bowl on the console. What does the `9999` mean? An element count maximum?

Comment: Yes, maxinum count. If the compiler supports that you can use the * instead.

Comment: Is there a way to format a REAL which evaluates to an integer without a trailing decimal point or fractional zeros (that is: instead of seeing `5.` or `5.000` I'd like it to just output `5` if the value is 5.000. the reason for this is that other programs I don't maintain read this file, so I'm trying to match a schema I know this other developer has already tested.

Comment: Probably not.         .

Comment: OK. Please see my edit; I'm a little stymied by some of the output.

Comment: The numbers do ot fit. However, you should ask the person whose answer you use. I offered f0.3 and the problem will not happen.

Comment: That problem won't, but it produces number like `.0000435` when what I prefer is a 0 in the ones place for numbers like that. BUT, in my testing, the `g0` appears to be working best.

Answer (score 6):

If your compiler has an appropriate level of Fortran 2008 support:

```
do i = 1, k
  write (7, "(*(G0,:,','))") s(:,i)
end do
```

`G0` uses processor dependent, "reasonable" values for the width and precision of the field for real numbers, with no leading or trailing blanks.

The `*` designates an unlimited format item, which means the entire format specification in the following parentheses pair is repeated until there are no more items.

The `:` control descriptor terminates output processing if there are no more elements.  This avoids a trailing comma.

Comment: This produces numbers like "0,322902.0,.000000,.000000,-1.375000" which is closer, but not a precise match.

Comment: Precise match to what?  If you want custom formatting beyond that provided by the standard descriptors, you'll need to write your own real to character conversion routine.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an example based on your code, however I do not know  how 
you are getting values of s, i.e, I do not know the rest of your code. 
This will print in column not in  row. Also look at
http://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/17_format.html
and try to figure out by your self

```
 program prgm1  
 integer k 
  real*4, allocatable   :: s(:,:) ! is the declaration
 ! ...
 k = 1
  allocate (s(16,k)) ! is the allocation
 ! then, in a loop later on:
  do i=1,k
     write (*,800) (s(j,i),j=1,16)
  end do
 800 format(f8.3,",")  
end  program prgm1


    program prgm1  
     integer k 
     real*4, allocatable   :: s(:,:) ! is the declaration
     ! ...
     k = 1
    allocate (s(16,k)) ! is the allocation
      ! then, in a loop later on:
     do i=1,k
    write (*,800) (s(j,i),',',j=1,16)
    end do
    800 format(16(f8.3,A))  
    end  program prgm1
```